# AVG Installer Error

Tags: windows-xp, avg-antivirus

My computer is running Windows XP Home Edition.

The avg I am using is expiring soon and so a pop out ask me to install AVG Anti-Virus Free Edition 2011. When the download is about to complete, I was asked to reboot the computer, I clicked "OK". After my computer restarted, there was a pop out saying:

> AVG Installer- Error  A system restart is required in order to continue with the installation. Please restart your system and try again.

Since the only option was "OK" I clicked it, and restarted my computer.

After restarting, the same pop-out appear. I could not download AVG Anti-Virus Free Edition 2011 as the pop-out keeps appearing if I run it or uninstall.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the odd antivirus installation issues I've seen have been caused by existing viruses.

Perhaps try the things listed on this post:

[How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the order below to disinfect your PC, then After this is done, uninstall AVG completely, reboot and install the new version.

1.) Make a boot AV disc then boot from the disc and scan the hard drive, remove any infections it finds, I prefer the Kaspersky disc myself. The New 2010 Kaspersky disc can update the AV dat files if you are connected to the internet at the time of scan and is suggested to update before the scan.
http://www.techmixer.com/free-bootable-antivirus-rescue-cds-download-list/

2.) Then:
Install free MBAM, run the program and go to the Update tab and update it, then go to the Scanner Tab and do a quick scan, select and remove anything it finds.

http://download.cnet.com/Malwarebytes-Anti-Malware/3000-8022_4-10804572.html

3.) When MBAM is done install SAS free version, run a quick scan, remove what it automatically selects.
http://www.superantispyware.com/download.html

These last 2 are not AV softwares like AVG, they are on demand scanners that only scan for nasties when you run the program and will not interfere with your installed AV, these can be run once a day or week to ensure you are not infected. Be sure you update them before each daily-weekly scan.

.